# Getting the newly added , deleted , modified values in hashmap at a particular state

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have an application , which operates on the hashmap at stages , in the sense it adds/deletes/modifies keys in different classes .
Thought of creating wrapper class by extending the Map class .
And Hacking the predefined put and remove methods .

**STAGE 1 :**

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("Key1","Value1");
hashMap.put("Key2","Value2");
hashMap.put("Key3","Value3");
hashMap.put("Key4", "Value4");
```

**Desired Result :**
*Added:

 Key1 : Value1

 Key2 : Value2

 Key3 : Value3

 Key4 : Value4*

**STAGE 2:**

```
hashMap.remove("Key1");
```

**Desired Result :**
*Removed:

Key1 : Value1*

**STAGE 3:**

```
hashMap.put("Key2", "ChangedValue");
```

**Desired Result :**
*Modified :

Key2 : ChangedValue*

What would be the best way or best logic to get only the diff ?
The dataStructure HASHMAP is fixed .

Comment: Yes create a class which extends Map, and override the methods to print what you want

Comment: Can you better explain what do you need?

Comment: You could just extend HashList to record your changes as they come, print them or store them. I added a basic implementation below.

Comment: @shashantrika, if the answer below was useful, may I ask you accept it?

Comment: @shashantrika, why did you un-accept? Is there anything I can do to add to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to extend HashMap to your own class, and record the changes:

```
class RecordHashMap extends HashMap<String,String> {
    private List<String[]> changes;

    public RecordHashMap() {
      super();
      changes = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    }

    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {

        if (containsKey(key)) {
            changes.add(new String[]{"modified",key,value});
        } else {
            changes.add(new String[]{"added",key,value});
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
     }

     @Override
     public String remove(Object key) {
         if (containsKey(key)) {
             String value = get(key);
             changes.add (new String[]{"removed",(String)key,value});
         }
         return super.remove(key);
     }

     public List<String[]> getChanges() {

         return changes;
    }
}
```

This way you can always check the last change, as they are all recorded. You can of course print them out as you record them - or later. You can add an index counter (to allow to only look at x recent changes), since you store them in an array list.