# How to extends java's HashMap to add hook operations when add/remove to/from this Map?

Tags: java, hashmap, hook, extends

I noticed HashMap has three method:

- afterNodeAccess
- afterNodeInsertion
- afterNodeRemoval

these hooks could help LinkedHashMap do something after nodes be accessed / inserted / removed, now I need extends HashMap to implement some abilities like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614982/getting-the-newly-added-deleted-modified-values-in-hashmap-at-a-particular-s) refered.

above question has an answer about override remove and put method, but it is not enough, because users can insert/remove by iterator or call method compute**.

Is there any way to help me reuse above three method, or some sample and effective ways, or just list all method and inner class I should override or overwrite, I will appreciate it.

Comment: You can't override final methods in java.util package

Comment: @belbix which method is final in HashMap.java ?

Comment: A lot of, putMapEntries for example. 
[HashMap.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html)

Comment: Also, the methods you want to override have the scope of the package and cannot be changed. Do not do that. This is bad practice.